# Python script to rotates the bits in its input two places to the right

Tags: python, bit-shift

Write shift script that expect a bit string as an input. The script shift Right rotates the bits in its
input two places to the right.

sample data: ‘0111110’,  '01110',  '00011111'

Shift : ‘1001111’,  '10011',  '11000111'

I tried like to access & modify it's first two digit & last two digit by converting into b=str(input)
then finding b[0], b[1], b[-1],b[-2], but it didn't work.
Please help, thanks a lot

Comment: what do you mean by didn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def shift_string(s):
   return s[-1] + s[:-1]

s = "01110"
for x in range(5):
  s = shift_string(s)
  print(x, s)
```

prints out

```
0 00111
1 10011
2 11001
3 11100
4 01110
```

so to shift `s` twice,

```
s = shift_string(shift_string(s))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should help I guess

```py
b = str(input())

# shift : how many bits you want to rotate
shift = 2
if shift == len(b):
    print(b)
else:
    print(b[-shift:] + b[:-shift])
```